# Bookshelf.js Where Like Dynamic Input

Tags: javascript, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I am trying to create a autocomplete search using Express/Bookshelf/Awesomeplete.

I am stuck in trying to figure out out to pass the search terms to Bookshelf using a Where Like query like such, that I am converting from PHP/MYSQL.

```
$query = mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['query']);
$query = htmlentities($query);  
SELECT SID, schoolName FROM schools WHERE schoolName LIKE '%$query%'
```

Here is what I have so far.

```
var terms = req.params.search;

new Model.School()
//This is the part that I can't get to work.
.query('where', 'schoolName', 'LIKE', '%'?'%',[terms])
.fetchAll({columns: ['SID', 'schoolName']})
.then(function (schools) {
   console.log(schools);
   var schools = schools.toJSON();
   res.json(schools);
 })
 .catch(function (error) {
    res.json({'message':'An error occured in your search'});
 });
```

If I change the above to:

```
new Model.School()
.query('where', 'schoolName', 'LIKE', '%american%')
.fetchAll({columns: ['SID', 'schoolName']})
.then(function (schools) {
   console.log(schools);
   var schools = schools.toJSON();
   res.json(schools);
 })
 .catch(function (error) {
    res.json({'message':'An error occured in your search'});
 });
```

The Bookshelf query functions as I need it to, but I want the query parameter to be dynamic.  I have tried a bunch of permutations, but can't get it to work.

Comment: Perhaps change your terms string to `var terms = "%"+req.params.search+"%"` then use ... `.query('where', 'schoolName', 'LIKE', terms)`. _(I'm not versed in Bookshelf enough for this to be more than an educated guess)_

Comment: You are a genius, never would have thought to put the full binding into the variable!!  As soon as I did it picked up like a charm.  If you add it as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my comment and your validation, it looks like the following works.

Basically you want to attach the '%' to the searched value before passing it into the `.query` LIKE clause.

```
var terms = "%"+req.params.search+"%";

new Model.School()
.query('where', 'schoolName', 'LIKE', terms)
.fetchAll({columns: ['SID', 'schoolName']})
.then(function (schools) {
   console.log(schools);
   var schools = schools.toJSON();
   res.json(schools);
 })
 .catch(function (error) {
    res.json({'message':'An error occured in your search'});
 });
```

Happy Coding. Gary.